# Windows 10 claims that my battery is charged up to 255%

Tags: laptop, battery, windows-10-v1903

I am running my Asus laptop without a battery (AC power only). When I click battery indicator in my brand new Windows 10 Pro 1903 I can see that everything seems OK:

[image]

But, when I hover it, I see some nonsense information:

[image]

Is there anything to be worried about (some hardware issue) or is this just a bug in Windows 10?

**EDIT**: *The described situation happens only when battery is taken of from the laptop (it is an Asus with removable battery). When battery is put inside, everything is OK -- both discharge and battery charge up processes seems to be normal as well as display values for battery indicator during the whole process.*

*The same goes for my another laptop (ThinkPad) with non-replaceable battery -- nothing unusual can be observed during both charge up and discharge of the battery.*

Comment: What happens when you unplug it? Does it stay at 255% or drop down to <100%?

Comment: You may have found a display bug in Windows, congratulations! :D Maybe someone else with a removable battery and Windows 10 can verify this.

Comment: Try updating or replacing your power manager driver. I have a laptop here with non-removable battery and another laptop here with removable battery. Neither machine does what you see above either on battery or plugged into AC

Comment: @TomCarpenter When I unplug then system is totally off in a matter of miliseconds, because there is no battery! :> When battery is plugged into the computer then everything works just fine (see edited question) for both discharge and battery charge up.

Comment: @John I don't wish to mess up with an unofficial drivers and as per official ones my Windows 10 claims that my system is up to date and there are no updates neither to drivers nor to any other area of system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value `255` is `FF` in hex and looks very similar to `-1` which is in hex
`FFFFFFFF` and is a favorite error code in Windows API.

It looks as if that icon uses a system call that failed, since there is no battery.

If the battery is physically still present, it might be better to take it out.
Otherwise, you may disable the Power system icon in
*Settings > Personalization > Taskbar > Turn system icons on or off*.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @harrymc's answer, I run a dual boot on a TUF-FX505DY and encountered a similar issue. The above mentioned status appeared in Windows, while Ubuntu showed the battery charging for a few seconds before displaying the alert "battery critical." It became evident that the issue couldn't be resolved at the OS level since both systems displayed similar errors.

Therefore, I manually disconnected the battery after opening the laptop. Upon restarting, the same behavior persisted. I presumed the battery had been shorted, but since didn't have a multimeter handy, I reconnected the battery to determine the cause.

It is now functioning, leading me to believe that the battery was either not properly attached to the mainboard or a static charge was discharged during my adjustments.

However, I only have anecdotal evidence and a lack of thorough insights. I wish I had found this solution prior to purchasing another £100 battery, as it cannot be returned.

Answer (score -2):

For me is something like this... 
Still don't know why this behaviour

from GetSystemPowerStatus (kernel32.dll)

ACLineStatus

The AC power status. This member can be one of the following values.

Value   Meaning
0 Offline
1 Online
255 Unknown status
BatteryFlag

The battery charge status. This member can contain one or more of the following flags.

Value   Meaning
1 High—the battery capacity is at more than 66 percent
2 Low—the battery capacity is at less than 33 percent
4 Critical—the battery capacity is at less than five percent
8 Charging
128 No system battery
255 Unknown status—unable to read the battery flag information

Comment: This is Super User site, not Stack Overflow. Giving programming-like solutions or answers that involved interacting with Windows API seems completely pointless here.